# How can I set a caller in ink! contract unit testing function?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, substrate, rust-ink

```
fn do_check(&mut self) -> Result<()> {
    let caller = self.env().caller();
    ...
}
```

I am writing a test function for `do_check` function. Here, I want to set a caller but not sure how to do that.

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use ink_lang as ink;

    #[ink::test]
    fn do_check_works() {
        let mut test = Test::new();
        // here I want to set a caller for calling do_check
        test.do_check();
        ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the caller using `set_caller` from [ink_env](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/):

```
let account = AccountId::from([0x1; 32]);
ink::env::test::set_caller::<ink::env::DefaultEnvironment>(account);
```

See the [examples](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/5fd51e264e5371b199d5fef53d8fadf15d1b90b6/erc20/lib.rs#L377) in the ink-examples repo for more details.

Comment: ink_env::test::set_caller::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>(bob);
    |                            ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `ink_env::test`

Comment: set_caller is not found in ink_env::test

Comment: You need to use the experimental unit test engine. Add this above your test `mod`: `#[cfg(feature = "ink-experimental-engine")]`. And add the dependency in your `toml` file: `ink-experimental-engine = ["ink_env/ink-experimental-engine"]`

Comment: Experimental engine flag is no longer needed